# How to design a "machine learning" method for a coin flip game

Tags: java, machine-learning

I am finishing up an algorithms class and the professor wants us to do an exercise in "machine learning" I pretty much have free reign in the project, but, it has to fall under the general umbrella of supervised learning.  So, I decided to do a coin flip simulation with bets being made by a computer player.  My idea is to make the coin biased and see if the computer can discover that bias when placing bets by using training data. I'm really not sure how to approach this..

An idea I had was to increment a win counter and pass that as a parameter into a method when determining the bets after a training round of say 100 bets. That way the computer player could make a decision to place more heads, if for example heads came up with 90% probability.  After sufficient training I think the computer would discover the bias.

I have code here to increment a win counter depending on the outcome, but, I'm not really sure where to go from there.  I.E. how to hold the corresponding data for if it was a win and if heads or tails came up and then use that information to place the bets in the next round.  Any advice would be greatly appreciated.  I am also open to using a different method if anyone thinks I am going about this the wrong way.

Please keep in mind that I am a second year undergrad and have very little knowledge of and exposure to actual machine learning techniques, hence the quotation marks in my question.

```
public class CoinFlip {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int bank = 500;
    int headsCount=0;
    int tailsCount=0;
    int winCounter=0;
    int lossCounter=0;
    String[] flipResults = new String[100];

    ComputerPlayer randomPlayer = new ComputerPlayer();
    Coin coin = new Coin();

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        randomPlayer.placeRandomBet();
        flipResults[i] = coin.flip();
        if(flipResults[i].equals("heads")){
            headsCount += 1;
        }
        else{
            tailsCount +=1;
        }
        if(flipResults[i].equals(randomPlayer.placeRandomBet())){
            bank += 50;
            winCounter+=1;
        }
        if(!flipResults[i].equals(randomPlayer.placeRandomBet())){
            bank -=50;
            lossCounter+=1;
    }
  }
}

public static class ComputerPlayer{

      double bet;
      String heads = "heads";
      String tails = "tails";

    public String placeRandomBet(){
        bet = Math.random();
        if(bet < .5){
            return heads;
        }
        else return tails;
    }

    public static String placeLearnedBet(int wins; int losses){
        //not sure where to start
    }

public static class Coin {

        double coin;
        String heads = "heads";
        String tails = "tails";

    public String flip() {
        if (Math.random() < .9) {
            return heads;
        } else {
            return tails;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: yeah sounds good to me, i think you should pass in the count for heads and tails and place your bet for whichever is greater

Comment: @FunctionR  If the coin is biased with .9 probability wouldn't that indicate a clear data set?  If not, in my eyes, my approach would be useless and by extension so would my program and idea..

Comment: Even if the coin is biased to 90% heads, you still shouldn't _always_ bet heads.  In fact, you should randomly bet heads 90% of the time and 10% of the time bet tails.  If you simply bet the most probable outcome (seen thus far) 1) you won't guess correctly until you've spent all of your money (so the "trial" bets should be small) and 2) there won't be any difference in behavior between a 60% biased coin vs. a 90% biased coin.

Comment: Also, I think you have a good premise here but I would say you are making your problem a lot harder by making it a betting game.  I would simply put in a random number for the bias and then see if your player can figure out the bias.  You are setting up a harder problem which is 1) you have to figure out the bias anyway and 2) you have to figure out an optimal betting scheme (which presumably maximizes profits the "fastest").

Comment: @Jared yes! I think that is exactly the idea I had in mind.  If for simplicity sake, I get 9/10 heads (in a training round) my betting function should randomly bet heads for 90% of the bets.  I'm not sure how to get there with my code though..  Good point on your second comment.  Thanks!

Comment: @Jared it is not correct that if a coin is biased 90% to heads that you should choose heads 90% of the time. The best strategy is actually to bet heads 100% of the time. The reason for this is that your expected gain when guessing heads 90% of the time is prob(heads | you bet heads) + prob(tails | you bet tails) = 0.9*0.9 + 0.1*0.1 = 0.82. That means you will guess correctly 82% of the time. Whereas if you always bet heads your expected gain is 0.9*1 + 0.1*0 = 0.9. Therefore it is better to always bet heads.

Comment: @BenjyKessler I'm not totally convinced you're completely right (and I'm _far_ from convinced that you are wrong).  You make the assumption that you should bet the same amount regardless.  It seems to me that you should bet less when betting tails since it's a "longer shot".  Perhaps you could do better by betting more when betting heads and betting less when betting tails.  I'm not sure though.

Comment: I claim that you should never bet tails. If you want you can change the size of your wager based on the variance of your prediction but this makes the problem a lot harder to analyze.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as finding the bias, that's not really all that difficult.  Basically, you would just guess the bias based on the number of heads out of the total number of plays and this ratio would give you the average bias.  So for instance if you got 51 heads and 49 tails, then you would guess the bias towards heads is 51%.

Ultimately, I think Benjy is correct that you should bet (heads or tails) based on which is more probable (according to your bias).  As you get more and more samples, your guessed bias will converge to the actual bias.  As far as the betting goes, from an expectation stand point, you should bet as much as possible; but from a realistic standpoint, this is not a good strategy (since you will eventually lose everything if you always bet everything unless the coin is 100% biased one way or the other).

A possible betting strategy could be "forward looking", i.e. assume you are going to make the same bet for the next n rounds and calculate the probability that you will win vs. lose.  You aren't directly trying to find the amount to bet rather you are trying to find the number n (the number of rounds to look forward) that give a certain probability of success.  The riskier the betting scheme, the smaller the accepted probability of success (i.e. the riskier the scheme) and the more conservative the betting scheme, then the larger accepted probability of success.  Once you find the number of rounds needed to guarantee you success (within your selected probability) you can then divide your pot by the number of expected rounds, that is bet the maximum amount such that if you lose every one of the next n rounds, you can still make a bet.

You can see that with the above, a conservative scheme would require more and more forward rounds and thus the bet would get smaller and smaller whereas with a risky scheme, the probability of success is small and thus would require fewer rounds and allow for a larger bet.

The last interesting thing is to decide how risky of a scheme you should choose.  Based on what I did, the less biased the coin (i.e. the closer to 50% chance of heads or tails), the riskier you should be and the *more* biased the coin (i.e. say 90% chance of tails or 90% chance of heads) the *less* risky your betting should be.  This sort of makes sense because if the coin is completely fair, then there isn't a betting scheme that will usually win so your best just making large bets and taking the 50% chance that you come out on top.  On the other hand, if the coin is extremely biased then the game itself isn't very risky and thus your betting scheme doesn't need to be very risky.  In the latter case, if you tend to make large wagers then you increase the chance that you lose everything vs. smaller wagers that all but guarantee a large payoff.  Keep in mind that as your pot grows, you can make larger and larger wagers without increasing your risk of losing money and thus if the coin is very biased it's quite easy to essentially get exponential growth in your pot.

Answer (score 1):

If you know that coin is distributed uniformly with a bias then you should always go with the majority. If you do not know the distribution of the coin then you want to use an algorithm called randomized weighted majority ([Regret Minimization](http://www.wisdom.weizmann.ac.il/~naor/COURSE/AGT/agt_dec_24th_regret.ppt)). This algorithm basically states that you should choose heads with probability #heads/#flips. As far as the weights are concerned if you know that the coin is distributed uniformly then you can estimate the bias and calculate the variance of your estimate. As the number of flips goes up the variance goes down like the square root of the number of flips. Your wagers should go up appropriately. IMO the weights make the problem a little less clear. What is your goal? To optimize your total expected gain? If so then it is not clear whether you should wager at all until the last coin flip at which point your variance is lowest and wager all your money then. This strategy however does not minimize your variance because all your money lies on one wager. Also if the coin is unbiased is it better to not wager at all or to wager all your money. In both cases you have 0 expected gain but with very different variances.

Comment: The full solution has to be far more nuanced than this.  This is because you must minimize the "risk-reward" (i.e. minimize the risk and maximize the reward).  If you start out with $500 it certainly does not make sense to bet $500 on the first bet.  If the coin is fair then your bets should tend toward $0 such that you end up with your starting amount (because that's the best you can be expected to do with a fair coin).  On the other hand, the more weighted the coin, the larger and larger your bets should become as you gain more bank, but you should _never_ bet you entire budget--ever.

Comment: I updated my answer. Why should you not bet your entire bank? If you are on the last coin flip then your prediction is going to be the most accurate so you could wait until the last roll and wager all your money then.

Comment: You should _never_ bet your entire bank because the chances of losing everything is assumed to be non-zero--once you lose everything you are done playing and you have "lost" effectively (because you have no more money to wager).

Comment: That's completely incorrect because you are talking about _expected values_ vs. what happens in reality.  On average, if you bet everything on the most probable value, then you are expected to "win".  The problem is the reality that when you lose, you don't get another chance (when you bet everything).  You are assuming that you can continually bet everything but not realizing that betting $0 nets you $0.

Comment: Are you assuming an infinite game? If the game is finite then you can bet the bank on the last round.

Comment: Assuming that betting it all the last round on the most probable outcome is correct, still, you shouldn't _always_ bet it all and you also shouldn't bet small every previous turn.  1) you need to make it to the last round and 2) you need to maximize your pot for the last round.  I don't think the expected value is the right metric.  The riskier your betting scheme the more potential profit but there's a smaller probability that you reach that potential vs. a more conservative betting scheme which has a lower potential for profit but a higher probability of success.